# Receiving the client url with data into wso2 esb and send response to another client

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

> If client sends the www.w3schools.org as url then i have to retrieve 
>   all data in this url like XML data ,HTML data into my service,
>
> and send all these  XML data and HTML data  to another client.
>
> IS this possible in wso2 ESB, if possible
>
> Can you give me any example for this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ESB for this.. Just write a simple service, which accepts a request from the user, and do processing then send back the response to client.